# listview only get one thing of my array

Tags: android, listview

I only get test30 as output whats my failure?

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   ListView listview;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

       Product[] items = {
               new Product("test1",07,07,2013),
               new Product("test2",07,07,2013),
               new Product("test3",07,07,2013),
       };

       ArrayAdapter<Product> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Product>(this,
               android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);

    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
       listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                   long id) {
               String item = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();
               Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
       });
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
       return true;
   }     
}
```

Product.java

```
public class Product {
    static String name;
    static int day;
    static int month;
    static int year;
    static String res; 

    public Product(){
        super();
    }

    public Product(String name, int day, int month, int year) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.day = day;
        this.month = month;
        this.year = year;

        Calendar thatDay = Calendar.getInstance();
        thatDay.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,this.day);
        thatDay.set(Calendar.MONTH,this.month-1); // 0-11 so 1 less
        thatDay.set(Calendar.YEAR, this.year);

        Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();

        long diff =thatDay.getTimeInMillis()- today.getTimeInMillis(); //result in millis
        long days = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
            res=String.valueOf(days);
        }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.name+this.res ;
    }
}
```

Comment: What were you expecting?

Comment: Even your question has errors ;)  I don't see "test30" anywhere in your code.  When you say you only get "test30", do you mean in the ListView, or in the Toast when you click an item?  BTW. Toast is a lousy way to debug.  If you learned how to use the debugger, you would find this problem in < 1 minute.

Answer (score 0):

Move your source array out of `onCreate()`. And you get "test30" because your `res` is zero.

Also you do not need to use `this.` the way you do. I undestand that you may want to avoid scope conflict, but the common pattern on android is just to prefix class members with `m`, so instead of having:

```
static String name;
```

you have

```
static String mName;
```

Comment: ok thank you it's running, how could I edit the onclick text. It should show the name and the date?

Comment: I respectfully disagree with both your suggestions.  Using `this` is good practice, mainly for code maintainability in the future.  Also, hungarian notation is not an android concept, and (at least in my opinion), it pretty much useless!  just call it `name`, because that's what it is!

Answer (score 0):

your mistake is, that (what i read from the code posted above) all fields are static (meaning they are once per class and not once per object). this makes the constructor calls you made in `onCreate` quite useless, since instead each product having a unique name, you overwrite the Product.name each time.

```
       Product[] items = {
           new Product("test1",07,07,2013), // Product.name = "test1"
           new Product("test2",07,07,2013), // Product.name = "test2"
           new Product("test3",07,07,2013), // Product.name = "test3"
       }
```

make your fields non-static (and probably private) and your problems should be gone.

edit1: for further reading about static/non-static fields go to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

edit2: and the zero behind the name should be as intended, since the difference between today and today is zero, you should test with different days ;-)